# innerHTML not rendering after replace

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

I am trying to get certain words to highlight in a page.  To accomplish this, I want to find all text nodes and replace only the specific word with a span that will highlight it.  The code appears to search and find the words in the text nodes properly, but the replace is not working.  I get this:

<span style="background-color: #FBC300;">foo</span>

And I want to get this:
foo (with a highlighted background)

```
function toRegExp(text) {
    return new RegExp(text, 'g');
}

function toSpan(text) {
    return '&lt;span style="background-color: #FBC300;"&gt;' + text + '&lt;/span&gt;';
}

function replaceText(squery, node) {
    node = node || document.getElementById("mainContent"); // base node

  for (node=node.firstChild;node;node=node.nextSibling){
    if (node.nodeType==3) {
        if (node.innerHTML) {
            node.innerHTML = node.innerHTML.replace(toRegExp(squery), toSpan(squery));
          } else { // support to IE
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(toRegExp(squery), toSpan(squery));
          }
    }
    else replaceText(squery, node);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to use the real tag delimiters (`<>`) instead of the HTMLEntities when creating the span. But you can't set HTML in a text node.

Comment: [`.replaceWith()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/replaceWith)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A text node can't contain elements, so you'll need to take the text node and split it into multiple nodes. For example, if you want to highlight `world` in `hello world`, you'll need to split it into a text node `hello` and an element `<span>world</span>`, which you can then style. Something like this:

```
function replaceText(squery, node) {
    node = node || document.getElementById("mainContent"); // base node

    for (node = node.firstChild; node; node=node.nextSibling) {
        if (node.nodeType == 3 && node.nodeValue) {
            var pieces = node.nodeValue.split(squery);
            if (pieces.length > 1) {
                // Split this node up into pieces
                for (var i = 0; i < pieces.length - 1; i++) {
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createTextNode(pieces[i]), node);

                    var span = document.createElement('span');
                    span.style.backgroundColor = '#FBC300';
                    span.innerText = squery;
                    node.parentNode.insertBefore(span, node);
                }
                node.nodeValue = pieces[pieces.length - 1];
            }
        }
        else
            replaceText(squery, node);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This fixed the problem and is highlighting the words properly.

Answer (score -2):

For me, this is working:

```
<html>
    <body>       
        <p>bla test bla</p>
        <script>
            function highlight(text) {
                document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace(text,'<span style="background-color:red">'+text+'</span>');
            }
            highlight('test');
        </script>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What did you change? And why did you change it?

Comment: `document.body.innerHTML =  ...` This is awful, you should not rewrite the entire `body` to just change a small bit in it.